# Getting 'E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations. Detailed error: INVALID_AUDIENCE' even after providing accurate client IDs

Tags: android, firebase, google-api-client, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have provided GoogleSignIn option in my app.

Here's my code:

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextView appName;
    ProgressDialog signinProgressDialog;
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        signinProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.signupCoordinatorLayout);

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.o_auth_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestId()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                    }
                } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    signinProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
                    signinProgressDialog.show();
                    signIn();
                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                    signinProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Error signing in!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
                signinProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("firebaseAuthWithGoogle", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("signin_successful", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                        signinProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("signin_unsuccessful", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            signinProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) SignupActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

I have 2 client IDs, one is Web client and another is Android client.

I have checked my client id's with my `google-services.json` file and my project on console.developers.google.com They all are matching.

But I'm still getting this error: `E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: INVALID_AUDIENCE
06-27 12:40:14.651 4443-4484/? D/AuthAccountOperation: id token request failed.`

What could possibly be causing this error?

Is it so that my app is no longer connected to my app on my console or is it something else?

Please let me know.

Comment: I was doing google sign in using Google API in my android app. Assuming your configs are all as per google document explained, here is a new thing I had to do.  When I used my code the sign-in feature functioned fine but when my developer used it he faced this issue, I solved it by using same "debug.keystore" for my and my developer's machine. It worked well.

Comment: This basically happens due to wrong finger print. verify your finger print with console.

Comment: And how do you do this verifying?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add SHA fingerprint for each android app on your project settings. If you are using Firebase, edit the below link with your project's name and then add the fingerprint for your app.

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}/settings/general/
```

Comment: @NiravPatel You would add certificate fingerprints for both debug and release keystroke files. Here's a [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) where to find the debug keystroke file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login success with google account，you should make these:
    1.upload an apk (e.g. packageName is 'com.example.xxx'& keystore's SHA1 is 'qwertyuiop....' ) to google developer console,then you get the ClientID.
    2.use the correct ClientID just got,and sign your apk with right keystore file which SHA1 is 'qwertyuiop...'.Generally,you could make it.

Still can not login success,one of steps above must be wrong,check it step by step.My guess,you keystore file may be wrong for your debugMode.

Comment: I think this is (at best) a wild guess about the nature of the problem; not worth a real answer; if at all, it should be comment.

Comment: are you judge this with guess？do you realize google login progress？SHA1 of keystore & package name are concerned about this. If he use correct clientID and packageName，Then he should check his keystore!

Comment: As said: this would make up an "OK" comment; but for an answer, such a one-sentence statement simply doesn't do. If you improve your answer I dont mind changing my "judgement".

Comment: In my opinion, this is likely the problem and at a minimum a reasonable "answer"  not worthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i'm quite late for this question. But you can solve this problem by updating your google-service.json file sync with firebase.

Tools-> Firebase
->Analytics->Connect to firebase

it will create your app or sync if its already there.

Regards